# PHP - Sending mail with through gmail?

Tags: php, gmail, imap

Is there any way to send mail from a gmail account to someone? And by "from" i mean so that it stores the email in the gmail inbox aswell...?

I've tried using imap, but i'm not sure if that's the correct way? Either way i get this error:

```
Warning: imap_mail() [function.imap-mail]: "sendmail_from" not set in php.ini or custom "From:" header missing in C:\xampp\htdocs\gmail\index.php on line 12
```

Any idas how to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try using smtp instead, Gmail will put your email in sent folder for you. All the instructions are provided in the settings page of your gmail account.

http://deepakssn.blogspot.com/2006/06/gmail-php-send-email-using-php-with.html

Comment: It's just an example, you can use any smtp mailer you want that is compatible with secure communications with SMTP servers.

Comment: The reason i didn't want to use PHPMailer was because i got so damn frustrated when i didn't find the correct downloadlink. Well i found the download link, and downloaded it, but i didn't get the right files. But i managed to find it now, and i got it working. Thanks for the suggestion! :)

Comment: I don't use PHP too often, so I just googled it. But I do send emails using ASPX trought GMAIL and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the same thing email clients do: Send your mail through SMTP and then create a mail in the Sent folder through IMAP.